# I get a blank page error in mod speed plugin

Tags: apache, nginx, centos, mod-pagespeed, directadmin

I use the Directadmin panel in the Centos 7 infrastructure.
I installed mod_pagespeed plugin for nginx_apache web service.

PHP Software works normally, but I have problems with the `<script> and <style>` tags embedded in the html code.

When these tags are in the code, the website opens as a white and blank page.

I couldn't find any log on this issue. Could you please help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you make a question there should be a minimum content as input, expected output, what did you try, what did you research and where are you stuck in... Could you show us your code?

Comment: Hi, my website address is http://hazirsite.org/ a simple single page html code. This is a problem when the first page is opened. You can see that the problem is corrected when you enter modpagespeed at http://hazirsite.org/?ModPagespeed=off.